# Replace occurance in a string with the result

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string:

```
{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"}
```

I want to convert it into this:

```
{key1:"value1",key2:"value2",key3:"value3"}
```

So I did something like this:

```
var output = str.replace(/"(.*?)":/, "$1:");
```

This way I get:

```
{key1:"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"}
```

So it works for the first key, but not for the rest. How can I use the replace method to replace all occurrences like I showed here?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to strip the quotes from around the keys?

Comment: is the end result also supposed to be a string? Or do you want to convert that JSON into an object? If you want the latter, just feed that string into `JSON.parse()`

Answer (score 6):

Use a global flag with your regex

```
str.replace(/"(.*?)":/g, "$1:");
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the regex:

```
var output = str.replace(/"(.*?)":/g, "$1:");
```